# Retrieve first 10 comments from .html file

Tags: php, jquery, readfile

I was goog for hours and just cannot find an answer. Please suggest:

Having a .html file that contains only user comments in paragraphs like:

```
<p>12/02/2012 4:32pm Mark</p>
<p>Hi! it's a nice demo! Really thankful</p>

<hr>

<p>11/02/2012 11:03am Miron</p>
<p>How to change the font size from CFD again?</p>

<hr>

<!-- AND LOADS OF OTHER <P><P> COMMENTS DELIMITED BY <HR> ... -->
```

There's 1000's of comments structured like this,
**I'd like to grab somehow the newest 10 (not by date, just the first 'ten' comments).** And I don't know how.

I know I can use jQuery's `.load('comments.html')` and than remove all the elements but the first 10 comments, or even include the whole file with PHP and than do the `.hide()` with **jQuery**... but it's a good idea to load the whole file for just 10 comments?

How to split that file and get inside an `<div id="latest_10_comments"></div>` the first 10 comments from the `comments.html` file?

Comment: Well, depending on the form of your comments, it may not be simply a matter of retaining the last 10 elements.  Are your comments always set up so the most recent is at the top of the file?  Is the file purely comments, or may there be other elements (other than <hr>) mixed in?  Is every comment always preceded by its date?

Comment: I would recommend using a database rather than a file.

Comment: @user1161318 No. The dates are fine. the comments are newest:first `<p><p> <hr> <p><p> <hr> <p><p> <hr>` and so till the end of line. I just need to split by the tenth `<hr>` (somehow) and get all to the beginning of file. (hope that clarifies my question) thanks

Comment: Is there no naming convention for comments? ie are they all just saved as <p></p>

Comment: *" but it's a good idea to load the whole file for just 10 comments?"* you don't have a choice unless you want to manipulate the html with server-side code.

Comment: @KevinB yeh... that's why I'm asking for suggestions, I was afraid you're true. Thanks

Comment: @Ginnani: It's not a big deal to do this without reading the entire file, since you tagged PHP in your post and one of the responses include PHP.  If you'll use PHP, it's not much extra work to just make it go through the file line by line and stop at 10 comments so you don't have to read the whole thing.

Comment: is that the whole structure of your html file?  You know you can use a selector inside the .load() url  to limit what you get in from page?

Comment: @wirey True, though that doesn't change the fact that the browser still has to read and parse the 1000's of comments first.

Comment: exactly, using jQuery's `.load('file.html #elementID')` but I have no ID's and as @KevinB said it could cost a lot of browser processing... for nothing.

Comment: @KevinB thats true.. it would be very inefficient since it does parse the whole file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1. You can use a RegEx pattern to match 2 p tags followed by hr and repeat the pattern for 10 times.

Solution 2. 
Idea from other answer(CHRIS), but as that has error in PHP, I am suggesting this.

```
    $comments = explode("<hr>", file_get_contents("/comments.html"));
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
       print($comments[$i]);
    }
```

Comment: Mainly took idea from @CHRIS here.

Comment: Where's the RexEx you are talking about?

Comment: @DamienPirsy I gave that as first thought came to my mind. Then edited for the solution. What is more important solutions or downvoting?

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, but basing on your comments it seems like you said something, didn't write anything from your idea but copied another guy's answer instead. Just saying

Comment: Anyways, the code I have written is even optimized and simpler and tested.

Comment: THis simply works. THanks! +1 and waiting a bit for some other suggestions

Comment: The one I gave is barebone optimal, couldn't think of any simpler. But credit goes to CHRIS for devising the fact that we could explode at the `<hr>`.

Comment: I already used in the past the explode as suggested around on the net, just the examples provided was so scarse and my lack of PHP knowledge... was the right mix for failure :) Thanks

Comment: Only just seen this. Thanks for fixing my code, I always rush my answers on Stackoverflow to make sure someone doesn't post the answer before me :)

Comment: While trying to fix your array count I found that its not necessary at all. :)

Answer (score 2):

I know you wanted a JavaScript solution but you could do this in PHP by using the explode function.

Something like this:

```
$comments = explode("<hr>", file_get_contents("/comments.html"));
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
   print($comments[$i]);
}
```

This creates an array called $comments which is each comment in comments.html separated by a

```
<hr>
```

tag.

Comment: @VisioN he mixed up with some other language there :P

Comment: Ah, sorry. Yeah; I'll fix that.

Comment: Actually I'd be more happy with some PHP instead of JS thanks I'll take a look at this example!

Comment: @CHRIS took you code(idea mainly) and made it more optimized.

Ginnani: I have tested my code too.

Comment: nope... still the oldest ones instead of the newest ones I suppose it's due to the `-10` you used but I'm struggling to get it done right (newest are on the top of file)

Comment: Oh. Newest are on the top of the file! I fixed it for you, should work now.

Comment: :) well this is funny. Thanks so much. +1 Can you please tell me more about the count() method?

Comment: Yeah; I didn't see your answer until a minute ago. The count function returns the length of an array. Some examples and whatnot can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd suggest reconsidering your approach to this problem entirely. Why are you storing everything an in HTML file this way? You should either store it as an XML file or store it in your database if you want to dynamically load certain comments on demand.

However, to answer your question you're going to need to use an X/HTML parser like PHP's [DomDocument](http://php.net/dom) if you want to do this in PHP. Here's a working example...

**EDIT** (*changed to reflect the OP's desired behavior*):

```
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile("comments.html");

// Get all the P tag elements in the DOM
$comments = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');

// Get only the first 10
$amount = 10; // number of comments you want
foreach ($comments as $num => $comment_nodes) {
    if ($num + 1 > $amount)
        break;
    echo $comment_nodes->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Look, the comments are stored FlatFile by a cool CMS. So the only thing I have is an undoctyped .html with just `<p>` and `<hr>` Thanks for the answer, I'll take a look at it

Comment: This works, it's just giving me the old comments from end of file :) THanks (I just have trouble to understand the code you wrote )

Comment: Right, it's assuming the comments were ordered in an ascending manner (oldest first to newest last). If they are ordered in a descending manner (newest first to oldest last) then you have to flip the `$start` and `$end` variables there.

Comment: I modified the example for you to give you the desired behavior, but it's relatively straight-forward how can modify that to do what you want.

Comment: May you please explain (Sorry and thanks for your time) all this math around... I can clearly see the output if formatted... while Lenin and CHRIS's answers do the job perfectly... I'm lost but really interested in your messy code :) (usually are bulletproof.)

Comment: yap... not only formatted... totally formatted. There's no one `<p>` tag any more, just a long string of text.

Comment: Messy problems have messy solutions :) What you're asking to do is very very messy, which is why I advised you against it first and fore-most and provided what I believe would be the most apt approach, but that's up to you. If you want to stick with messy here you are :)

Comment: Still I don't get it why there's no <p> tag any more (which I like a lot cause I suppose I can hardcode some new tags instead!) **EDIT:** I did it by adding again some `<p>. $comment_nodes->nodeValue, PHP_EOL .</p>`. And raised the amount to `20` cause I have two `p` tags /per/ comment. :) Why whould you advise for this solution against the other ones? Thanks

Comment: Because what I'm demonstrating here is how to output the **nodeValue** after having parsed the HTML. It was an **example** to show you how to work with the provided solution. I twas not meant for you to simply copy and paste and get the exact result you wanted in your code. I linked you to the documentation that you need to read in order to understand how DomDocument works. You can easily achieve what you want a number of different ways. This is one of them. The other solutions provided do similar things, but each has adverse side effects depending your requirements, which you never made clear

Comment: I don't recommend either solution, to be honest. I made my recommendations explicitly clear in my answer. Use a database (or at the very least use an XML document that would actually be sane). But because you want to use this messy solution to your problem I've provided you with the least messy answer I can. DOM is an HTML parser. That's its job. If you want to parse HTML that would be my answer. If you want to hack together something that may or may not work in any given set of circumstances go with the other answers. They'll make an educated guess at best.

Comment: True, I read my question and I cannot see I asked for keeping the `p` tags. I'm really sorry. But I really appreciate your help!  +1 I'll take a closer look at the DOCS and I'll revise the answers. Thanks.

Comment: I need to warn about DomDOcument object. If the HTML is malformed the solution will make your life hell. And CHRIS or my solution is not only easier but also is super fast compared to DomDocument approach. This approach is a DOM parser which works on well formatted HTML/XML.

Comment: @GoogleGuy made a good point, the questioners are not expected to just copy and paste codes. You should learn each of the answerers approaches. For example CHRIS at first tried to devise you with older comments. What if you need something like that later? So, you should every stone be turned.

Comment: And @Ginnani your belief 'messy codes usually are bulletproof' is a wrong concept. Do not blindly believe in such. You should keep a habit of [RTFM](en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM).

You see I first suggested RegEx and after submitting I found CHRIS's approach is the killer. So I gave a modified solution to fit it. RegEx does the job but hard to configure, also is time complex.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("<p>").each(function(index, value)
{
    //Do what you want here
}
```

This will cycle through all your `<p>`. If you know the order of the elements then you can do what you want with them based on `index`.

Comment: AFAIK you can do: `$("<p>").each(function( i ){  i += 1 ; });` :) thanks. Is there a PHP way instead of loading the whole file? or also with jQuery... ?

Comment: I know that that is jQuery, thanks, just asking to use AJAX but instead of loading an exact `file.html #id` to use `file.html p` :) and BTW you're missing a `);`